# Represent the following sentences in first order logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

**Q) Represent the following sentences in first order logic is this the right?**

**1)  John is intelligent than all other student in his class.**

FOL:    ∀X∶Student(X)→Intelligent(john,X)

**2)  Neiher Alex nor John is unhappy.**

FOL:     ¬(happy(alex) ∨ happy(john))

**3)  Some dogs are domestic pets. *(which one is correct)***

FOL:    i) ∃X∶Dog(X)→DomesticPets(X)   **(or)**

ii)   ∃X∶(Dogs(X) ∧ DomesticPets(X))

**4)  Some turtles are faster than rabbits.**

FOL:    ∃X∶Turtle(X)  ∧ Rabbit(Y)→faster(X,Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some dogs are domestic pets. Should be the second one
  $$ ∃X∶\text{Dogs(X)} ∧ \text{DomesticPets(X)}$$
  To see why it's not the first one, apply distributive law of $\exists$ over $\to$ we have 
  \begin{align}
  &∃X∶\text{Dog(X)}→\text{DomesticPets(X)}\\
  \equiv&\forall X:\text{Dog(X)}→\exists X:\text{DomesticPets(X)}
  \end{align}
  It basicly means if everything are dog, then something is a DomesticPet, clearly isn't what we want to say.
- Some turtles are faster than rabbits. Same mistake:
  \begin{align}
  &∃X∶\text{Turtle(X)} ∧ \text{Rabbit(Y)}→\text{faster(X,Y)}\\
  \equiv&\forall X∶\text{Turtle(X)} ∧ \text{Rabbit(Y)}→\exists X:\text{faster(X,Y)}
  \end{align}
  That is if everything are Tutle and $Y$ is Rabbit, then $\dots$ just make no sense.
  Instead we write
  $$\exists X:\text{Turtle(X)} ∧ \forall Y:\text{Rabbit(Y)}\to\text{faster(X,Y)}$$
  This is some Turtle faster than all the rabbits.